# Search for word in a phrase

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the following code to loop through data column for keywords such as "personal" or "fraud" and copy rows with these keywords to a separate tab.

My code does not match when the keyword is within a phrase (e.g. "personal expenses").

```
Sub pooling()

a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To a
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 10).Text = "Personal" Or _
         Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 10).Text = "Fraud" Then
         Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
         Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
         b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
         Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
         Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
    End If    
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: the fucntion InStr can be used to check if "this" in Cell.Value. It returns an integer value which means you check InStr(1. Cell.Value, "yourstring")>0. If its found it will be the position in which the string starts. So greater than 0 should suffice

Comment: i.e. "ohyeswhynot" - InStr(1, cell.value, "yes")>0= 3 b/c its starts at position 3. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks for advice, the following code worked for me  "If InStr(.Cells(i, "J").Text, "Personal") Or _ ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `Like` and the wild-card `*`, as in the code below:

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 10).Value2 Like "*" & "Personal" & "*" Or _
         Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 10).Value2 Like "*" & "Fraud" & "*" Then
```

---

Full modified shorter version of your code (without using `Activate`)

```
Sub pooling()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False  ' turn off screen updating >> accelerate run time

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To a
        If .Cells(i, 10).Value2 Like "*" & "Personal" & "*" Or _
             .Cells(i, 10).Value2 Like "*" & "Fraud" & "*" Then

             ' find last row in "Sheet2"
             b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

             ' copy>>paste is a 1-line syntax
             .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1)
        End If
    Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I think the performance of like vs Instr might be significantly different. In the middle of testing

Comment: Maybe add an `Option Compare Binary` to show OP the difference between CI/CS (I think he wants Case Sensitive as first letter is captial) @T. Chern recognize the replaced `Select`s (avoid them, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba except you prepare an user-action) and the elegance of the `With` statement!

Comment: Thanks, it worked and that is exactly what I looked for.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best with `AutoFilter()`:

```
Sub pooling()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' reference "Sheet1" sheet
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) ' reference referenced sheet column A range from row 1 (header) to last not empty cell
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*Personal*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="*Fraud*" ' filter referenced range with wanted criteria
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0) ' reference referenced range offsetted one row down to skip headers
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' if any filtered cells then copy their entire row and paste them to "Sheet2" starting from its column A first empty row after last not empty one
            End With
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```